# How to rename value in a List without creating a new one?

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings `List<string> blobsToCopy`

```
var newList = blobsToCopy.Select(GetDiskNameWithoutFolder);
private static string GetDiskNameWithoutFolder(string path) {...}
```

How to change all values in the `blobsToCopy` without creating a new `IEnumerable<string>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't use LINQ, just use a simple for loop and replace each item with its  modified version.

```
for (var i = 0; i < blobsToCopy.Count; i++)
{
     blobsToCopy[i] = GetDiskNameWithoutFolder(blobsToCopy[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, what's wrong with a good old-fashion for loop?

```
for(var i=0; i < blobsToCopy.Count;i++)
{
    // do whatever....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, strings are immutable, so you can't edit those directly. Instead you could edit your list with `blobsToCopy[i]`. This will keep your list intact and let you edit which string the element of the list points to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the ForEach linq implementation. Don't have a c# compiler available at the moment, so I can't test this.

```
list.ForEach(c => c = GetDiskNameWithoutFolder(c));
```